# run arena model from macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am a student in the final year in Engineering studies, and my project consists in building an arena model. In the final step, I want to activate arena from excel.

I created a macro in excel

```
Sub ARENA_EXECUTE()
    m = Shell("""program_path"" ""model_path""", vbMaximizedFocus)
End Sub
```

I created a vba code in the model

```
Sub ModelLogic_DocumentOpen()
    Dim m As Model
    Set m = ThisDocument.Model
    m.Go
End Sub
```

I could open the model but in the first replication something goes wrong and this message appears:

> WARNING: A warning was generated at simulation time 0.0 while
>   evaluating REPLICATE expression. You have attempted to use
>   interprocess communication (IPC), but IPC was not successfully
>   initialized. You must include VBA or user code to enable this feature.
>   See the Real-time Features and User-coded C/C++ topics in the Advanced
>   Options section of the Arena help for more information. Any messages
>   to be sent will be echoed to the screen. 17131:IPCINI

Could you help me fix this problem.

Comment: Try this: `Dim m As Arena.Model` instead of this `Dim m As Model`

Comment: `IPC was not successfully initialized` 
What are the required steps for initializing IPC with the Arena? What is  the system environment passed to the Arena through `Shell`?

Comment: See this free online book: https://books.google.com/books?id=5SezxR5q4mYC&pg=PA418&lpg=PA418&dq=Arena+vba&source=bl&ots=1dVhae7Tpp&sig=inItkPbqO4mZ7Dupj2CeeKsSqTw&hl=pl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Arena%20vba&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add more details. If you are using shell programming.

for example , below program will open a folder
' Shell "explorer.exe" , vbNormalFocus